# Can I combine subdomains in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I have 2 separate domains in my Google Analytics: `abc.com` and `xyz.abc.com`. The second domain is 3rd party shopping cart.

Right now the reporting for each is separate. I want to have them together so I can eventually set up goals and conversion tracking.

Answer (score 1):

In case of 1 top-level and multiple subdomains you can set up your tracking code to track everything related to the top-level domain. This will result in one profile that will contain all the traffic data related to all the sites within that domain (including subdomains). After this -if need be- you can separate the sites with advanced segments.